# Teleprompter app in Xcode using Swift

Tags: swift, core-animation

I have finished an online course in iOS development on Udemy and I'm ready to start developing my first (real) app.

My goal is to make a teleprompter app similar to: https://itunes.apple.com/dk/app/video-teleprompter-lite/id1031079244?mt=8

To start with, I would like to create just the moving text. I have looked at various concepts such as Core Animation, Text View, Segue from one view controller to another etc. But none of them seem to be able to display the moving text in the proper "teleprompter way".

I would really appreciate suggestions as to how to start/which relevant concepts to look at in this context.

Comment: Use an UIView and draw directly into it yourself.

Comment: I will give it a try. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reading up on UIDynamics, UIPushBehavior.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uidynamicanimator

Comment: Thx. I will give it a try.

Comment: Please don't give link-only answers. Links can break at anytime.